# HTML code not recognized after PHP loop

Tags: php, html, forms, while-loop

Im trying to create a form within a php while loop using echo.  Following the while loop I would like to continue the form in HTML.  The while loop uses a variable created by scandir() to display a list of files in a directory via a drop-down menu i.e. 'select' and 'option' tags.

The interesting bit is when I start my html again after the php loop, my browser (FIREFOX) doesn't display the first few lines of code.  More specifically it doesn't recognize the lines between the comments

```
<!-- FROM THIS POINT --> ...code that isn't displayed... <!-- TO THIS POINT-->
```

See simplified code below. Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- HTML... -->
<form action = "" method = "post"> 
Input File: <select name="drop_down_name" >

<?php

$dir = "/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/IESE";
$files = scandir($dir, 1); 
$i = 0; 

while($i <= count($hypo_files)) { 
  echo "<option value = $files[$i]> $files[$i] </option>";
  $i = $i + 1;
}

?> 
<!--FROM THIS POINT -->
<fieldset>
<legend>Hypo Query:</legend>
<br>
Input Value: <!-- TO THIS POINT --> <input type = "text" name = "some_value">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an end `SELECT` tag.

```
</select>    <!-- here -->
<!--FROM THIS POINT -->
<fieldset>
```

Not closing tags can have weird effects like that you see with partially missing code.

Also, put your option values in quotes:

```
echo '<option value="'.$files[$i].'">'.$files[$i].'</option>';
```

Comment: +1 correct answer. The browser is expecting `<option>`, `<optgroup>` or `</select>`, and OP is giving it `<fieldset>`...

Comment: You are a god among peasants!  Thanks a billion!

Comment: Welcome! Thank me by "click to set this answer as your accepted answer" with a green check. That is how you do it here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to close SELECT tag. first close the SELECT tag and then try.i hope  it will work.
?>

Answer (score 0):

Your `<select>` tag is not getting closed. Please close that & it would work